# Меню с помощью библиотеки Swiper

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

Здравствуйте!

Кто работал с библиотекой **[Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/#.WQnTQ1WLSUk)** подскажите, пожалуйста, следующее:

Хочу сделать тач меню, чтобы на мобильных устройствах меню работало, как в приложении ВК.

[Вот сам пример](https://jsfiddle.net/6y5Lgod0/10/)

Вытаскивать меню хочу с помощью:

```
<div class="container1"></div>
```

движение вправо открыть, а закрыть можно будет только по клику (ширина станет для этого класса 100%), а само меню, которое вылезет - движение влево закрыть.

`class="container1"` сейчас в примере подсвечен цветом, в реальности он будет без цвета.
Как уже выше отметил, что при открытии меню к `div` с классом `container1` добавляется класс `cross2`, для того, чтобы `div` был на всю ширину, чтобы кликнув по нему, можно было закрыть меню. Также к `<div class="container2">` добавляется класс `cross` со значением `left:0;`, так как сейчас стоит `left:-100%;`

Но что-то мой пример не работает. Думаю многим будет интересно это решение.
Надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Хотя бы вытащить меню и затащить обратно его:)